# Не могу сохранить файл в Android N

Tags: java, android

Использую такой метод, для сохранения фотографий, на Android N, не создает директорию и не сохраняет фотографию, что делаю неправильно? Как сделать, что бы создавало директорию и  сохраняло фотографии?

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

В Манифесте прописаны такие permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Метод, где проверяются permissions:

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void captureImage(){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        2);
            }
            else{
                saveImage();
            }
        }
        else{
            saveImage();
        }

    }
```

Метод `saveImage()` :

```
public void saveImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File sentDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Imessenger/Sent/");
    sentDirectory.mkdirs();
    File photo = new File(sentDirectory, "Pic.jpg");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Метод  `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                saveImage();
            } else {
            }  
    }
```

Comment: т.е не создается только на андроиде N, на 4,5, 6 все создается?

Comment: На 4, 5 создается, на 6 не тестировала

Comment: ну тогда думаю проблема в пермишионах <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @PeDuCKA Так для сохранения файла разве нужен READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? Должно быть достаточно WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Оба прописаны в Манифесте.

Comment: @PeDuCKA Или нужно делать checkSelfPermission для READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE при сохранение тоже?

Comment: видимо не достаточно=), попробуй спроси, не так долго ведь=)

Comment: @PeDuCKA Запросила permission для READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, программа не заходит в requestPermissions(), а сразу заходит в  saveImage(), не крашится, не выдает ошибок, но не создает директорию и не сохраняет файл.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50125/discussion-between-peducka-and-lucky-girl).

Comment: @PeDuCKA О, помогло! RxPermissions - классная библиотека! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

> на Android N, не создает директорию и не сохраняет фотографию

См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455957/966789

(Android added new permission model for Android 6.0 Marshmallow)